# How to check user query history based on a table or view in BigQuery

Tags: google-bigquery

I am trying to find the people who query on particular BigQuery table, is there any ways I can find the history using SQL?

I tried to use INFORMATION_SCHEMA table in BigQuery but can't find anything relate to the history query usage based on table

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried INFORMATION_SCHEMA.JOBS ?

https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/information-schema-jobs

You can try

```
select project_id,user_email from project-id.`region-xyz`.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.JOBS_BY_PROJECT where query like "%table_name%"
```

This should be able to give you list of users who has executed any kind of your query utilizing your table.